# Unable to build my code in visual studio 17 as the build option is greyed out entirely

Tags: visual-studio

I have some C++ code in visual studio 17 on macOS. For some reason, I can't do anything with it such as build it, debug it or anything. [This photo shows what I get when I try to build the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc95T.png)

I tried reinstalling but that did nothing as well.

Comment: You need to open/create a project, a C++ file alone cannot be built.